# Parsing JSON in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to populate the data that Im getting from Webservice - JSON response in Template.

My Service integration code:

```
serviceRequest  = requests.get(ServiceSettings.getCitiesURL(),  
headers={
"Content-Type":servicesettings.JSON_CONTENT_TYPE,
"Accept":servicesettings.HEADER_ACCEPT 
})                                  
dataJson = serviceRequest.json ()
```

Response that Im getting is

```
{"cities": [{"latitude": "21.321", "cityIdentifier": "GOOD", "cityName": "NY", "longitude": "23.23432"} , {"latitude": "1.321", "cityIdentifier": "GOOD", "cityName": "CA", "longitude": "3.23432"}
], "statusMessage": "OK", "statusCode": 200}
```

I'm trying to iterate it in DJango Tempalte (HTML) like below but am not not able to list the cityName

```
{% for objCities in cityList%} 
    {% for objCity in objCities.citiess%} 
        {{objCity.cityName}}
    {% endfor%}
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: You're not parsing it in your template: `requests` is doing the parsing, in your view. In your template, you're iterating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your loop, you were trying to access a string with an index. So `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str` was raised.

Consider following:

```
{% for objCity in cityList.cities %} 
    {{objCity.cityName}}
{% endfor%}
```

This will work.